# Inno setup reading binary files

Tags: binary, inno-setup, pascalscript

What commands to use to open, read binary files under inno setup script.

I am not interesting for text files only for bin files. I couldn't find anything inside inno setup help.

Regards

Comment: Ok give me some time to give it a try.  Thanks

Comment: I did not run it but seems that this piece of code will do the job from me. Thanks